# How to get Checked check boxes length

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Trying to get checked check boxes length but getting 0 while they are all checked.

I have a table and it's row's containing td's of check boxes.
Each input type checkbox has class name " check ".

Having master checkbox outside the table and that is responsible for select/Deselect all check boxes inside the table.

Now I want to see if at least one check box is checked by clicking button.

```
var allCheckBoxes = $('.check :checkbox:checked');
console.log(allCheckBoxes.length);
```

It's getting nothing but zero :(

```
            <table id="checkboxTable" class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Table name</th>
                    <th>Gen A</th>
                    <th>Gen B</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

            @foreach($data as $k => $table)
            <tr class="trcheck" id="{{$table}}">
                <td>{{$table}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{$table}}[]" value="controller" class="check"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{$table}}[]" value="model" class="check"></td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="checkbox_gen_object(this);" id="{{'genbtn'.$i}}" class="genSingle btn btn-primary">
                        Generate
                    </button>
                </td>

            </tr>

            @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: If this is true: `Each input type checkbox has class name " check ".` then the length of your allCheckBoxes variable can't be anything else than 0

Comment: Without your html I can say for sure, but try `$('.check:checkbox:checked');` guessing by that your checkbox has the class `check`

Comment: sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Check my answer below it will definitely help you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myfunction(){
var mylength=$(".a").filter(':checked').length;
alert(mylength);
$("#leng").val(mylength);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  
  length: <input type="text" id="leng" name="user"><br>
  I have a bike: <input type="checkbox" class="a" name="vehicle" value="Bike"><br>
  I have a car: <input type="checkbox" class="a" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>
  I have an airplane: <input type="checkbox" class="a" name="vehicle" value="Airplane"><br>
  <input id="btn" onclick="myfunction()" type="button" value="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the space in `$('.check :checkbox:checked')` since your object with the class `check` is your checkbox;

You also don't need the `:checkbox` selector, just use `$('.check:checked').length`

**Working demo**

```js
function checkbox_gen_object(obj){
  console.log($('.check:checked').length)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="checkboxTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Table name</th>
      <th>Gen A</th>
      <th>Gen B</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="trcheck" id="{{$table}}">
      <td>{{$table}}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{$table}}[]" value="controller" class="check"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{$table}}[]" value="model" class="check"></td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="checkbox_gen_object(this);" id="{{'genbtn'.$i}}" class="genSingle btn btn-primary">
                        Generate
                    </button>
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="trcheck" id="{{$table}}">
      <td>{{$table}}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{$table}}[]" value="controller" class="check"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{$table}}[]" value="model" class="check"></td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="checkbox_gen_object(this);" id="{{'genbtn'.$i}}" class="genSingle btn btn-primary">
                        Generate
                    </button>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```